# (?P<name>.*?) retrieve empty string when groups

Tags: python, regex

I am using python regular expression to parse visual studio .sln file, codes as following.

```
pattern_project_config = r'\s*\{(?P<project_id>.*?)\}\.(?P<sln_config>.*?)\|(?P<sln_platform>.*?)\.(?P<sln_action>.*?)\s=\s(?P<project_config>.*?)\|(?P<project_platform>.*?)\s*'
test = r'{2DE66161-A453-4EDE-A2E8-C4104D6DFED5}.Debug|Android.ActiveCfg = Debug|Android-arm64-v8a'
pattern = re.compile(pattern_project_config)
matches = pattern.match(test)
project_id = matches.group('project_id')
sln_config = matches.group('sln_config')
sln_platform = matches.group('sln_platform')
sln_action = matches.group('sln_action')
project_config = matches.group('project_config')
project_platform = matches.group('project_platform')
print(project_id, sln_config, sln_platform, sln_action, project_config, project_platform)
```

But why the last one "project_platform" is empty string, what's wrong with my regular expression statement?

Comment: What's your input string?  Are the other values correct?

Comment: Input string is "test" variable. I notice appending $ into the regex pattern can fix my issue. But I still wonder the theory of this behavior.

Comment: `.*?` is a *non-greedy match* - it will initially match nothing at all, and only increase in size (one repetition at a time) if necessary to make the rest of the regex succeed.  But the rest in this case is `\s*`, which *cannot fail* - it will happily match nothing at all, so there's no reason for the `.*?` to ever match anything.  Putting `$` at the very end is a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `?` form `(?P<project_platform>.*?)` (or even from every group since it is not needed when using your test string). And you can use `groupdict()` to get all values in a dictionary:

```
import re
pattern_project_config = r'\s*\{(?P<project_id>.*)\}\.(?P<sln_config>.*)\|(?P<sln_platform>.*)\.(?P<sln_action>.*)\s=\s(?P<project_config>.*)\|(?P<project_platform>.*)\s*'
test = r'{2DE66161-A453-4EDE-A2E8-C4104D6DFED5}.Debug|Android.ActiveCfg = Debug|Android-arm64-v8a'
result = pattern.match(test).groupdict()

{'project_id': '2DE66161-A453-4EDE-A2E8-C4104D6DFED5',
 'sln_config': 'Debug',
 'sln_platform': 'Android',
 'sln_action': 'ActiveCfg',
 'project_config': 'Debug',
 'project_platform': 'Android-arm64-v8a'}
```